# String function won't return string

Tags: c++, return

I cant seem to `return str` in my `RemSpacePunct` function.

I wanted to make a function that removes spaces in a string but when I run the code, it won't remove the space.

```cpp
string RemSpacePunct(string str);
string sort(string str);

int main(){ 
    string s = "partial men";
    
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    
    RemSpacePunct(s);   
    cout << s;  
}

string RemSpacePunct(string str)
{
    //add code here
    int s, i;
    
    s = str.length();
    
    for(i = 0; i < s; i++){
        if(isalnum(str[i]) == false){
            str.erase(i, 1);
        }       
    }   
    return str;
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the return value when you call the function: `s = RemSpacePunct(s);`

Comment: When you call `RemSpacePunct(s);`, you should not expect this to have any effect on the value of `s` within the function, *no matter what code* you write in the function body. This is because you have passed the string by value - making a copy - and are expecting to receive the changes using the return value, but you do nothing with that return value.

Comment: Sidenote: You will go out of bounds at some point, because but you iterate from 0 to the original length of `str` and don't take into account that `str`s length decreases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value. `str` is **copied** when it's passed to the function, so any modifications you perform on the argument aren't reflected back to the original value. Instead, you should return a modified value - which you do, but you then ignore it instead of using it:

```
string result = RemSpacePunct(s);   
cout << result;
```

Comment: Or use pass-by-reference to save the value. It is not clear what the real intention is.